# Outlook email alerts every hour? (not immediate)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, alert

I'm starting to use MS Outlook 2010 for work and I would like email alerts only to show up every hour or so, instead of showing up right when the message is received. Is there a way to make Outlook do this?

After having gone through the Options menu and after some research in Google, I haven't found anything useful.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are not checking your email for 1 hour then why just not setup "Send and Receive" option to check at every 1 hour. Because it looks like that there is no option to delay notification for emails.

Answer (score 3):

What version of outlook are you using? and do you want to only receive emails once an hour or just have it alert you every hour? because in later version of outlook you can make it to where it will only send and receive once every hour and then it will alert you about your emails.

Comment: What i did at my job is that I had my users outlooks run a rule every hour or so> So i wrote a small batch file that ran outlook rules (you can make it do what ever you want in outlook i.e. send and receive...etc) then i scheduled a windows task to run that program every hour. Simple enough. They added the function of controlling outlook programatically in 2007. Let me know if you would like me to research and see if i can find the cmd scripts to run the send and receive.

Comment: Either one would work for me! Ideally, though, the message would come in immediately but the alerts would only happen every hour. I also added the Outlook version (2010) to the question.

Comment: Follow the steps at this website it will help a lot. I recently came across this website. you can set your outlook to offline mode and set the send and receive to automatically come in every hour or so. Much easier.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/schedule-when-a-send-receive-command-runs-HA010117941.aspx

but there are other things you can do, i have tried looking up the cmd script to run "send and receive" in outlook but to no avail but i know it is possible. Just some more digging on how or what the proper syntax is for a script and not a VB program or macro.

Comment: *make it to where it will only send and receive once every hour*...this only works if you [don't have an Exchange-based email account](https://superuser.com/a/863769/213131). Lots of people *do*, making this unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

No the alert settings are only for how long the alert is displayed and the transparency. You could turn off alerts and find timer software that could run once an hour to remind you to check your email.

[image: Alert]